# Can update a users password in localhost but not on shared hosting server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is the function to update user password

```
function update_systemusers_password($input)   {   
     $systemusers = users::find($input['userid']);   
     $systemusers->password = bcrypt($input['password']);  
     $systemusers->save();   
}
```

however it doesn't update in shared hosting server

Comment: What does it say in the hosting server? Any errors thrown?

Comment: there is no error message it says successful but password is not updated

Comment: You need to start debugging! Does the `update_systemusers_password()` method even execute? Try logging an arbitrary string in the method at different points or echo-ing a response to see at what point things are going wrong.

Comment: you may be haveing issue with .env.php  or database.php

Comment: you should use localhost in host name because you cannot connecting remotely from inside the server.

Comment: what is the PHP version in your shared server ????? @akash

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to confirm that your function is execute or not. Try something like this to make sure.

```
function update_systemusers_password($input)   {   
 dd($input); //  it will show the all of input
 $systemusers = users::find($input['userid']);   
 $systemusers->password = bcrypt($input['password']);  
 $systemusers->save();   
}
```

if dd(); print all the value of request then remove the dd(); inside the function and write some condition for confirmation.

```
function update_systemusers_password($input)   {   
 $systemusers = users::find($input['userid']);   
 $systemusers->password = bcrypt($input['password']);  
 if($systemusers->save()){
  dd("save successfully");
 }
 else{
  dd("found error");
 }   
}
```

Comment: it shows another users id while updating own password.how can it be resolved.